# Why aren't my values adding up in my program?

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with a function I was helped with on here, and I'm trying to understand it and correct it.

Here's the function (with some commenting/printing thrown in simply to help me debug)

```
def accumulate_by_category(word_values, cat_sums, cats):
        for word, value in word_values.items():
                print word
                for cat in cats[word]:
                        print cat
                        #cat_sums[cat] += value
                        cat_sums[cat].append(value)
                print cat_sums
```

Now, word_values is supposed to look something like this:

```
{'a': 4, 'angry': 0, 'sad': 0, 'grateful': 0, 'happy': 0}
```

cat_sums is supposed to look like this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'composed': [0], 'elated': [0], 'unsure': [0], 'hostile': [0], 'tired': [0], 'depressed': [0], 'guilty': [0], 'confused': [0], 'clearheaded': [0], 'anxious': [0], 'confident': [0], 'agreeable': [0], 'energetic': [0]})
```

and cats is supposed to look like this:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'depressed': ['sad'], 'elated': ['happy', 'grateful', 'a'], 'hostile': ['angry']})
```

Basically, what the function is trying to do, is take each of the values in word_values, and add those ultimately to cat_sums. That's not currently what is happening - for some reason none of the values are appending. I'm having trouble figuring out quite why - when I try to `print cat`, it comes up blank. However `print word` gives me a list of words. Theoretically, for cat in cats[word] should bring up each of the terms in cats, but it does not.

What am I doing wrong?

I ultimately just want to add all of the values to cat_sums, so that I can write it to a database. Also, would I have to return the value of cat_sums to be able to do this?

This is my database writing code (catnums is the argument submitted to cat_sums):

```
for key in catnums:
        x = catnums[key]
        for value in x:
                cmd = "UPDATE resulttest SET value=\"" + str(value) + "\" WHERE category=\"" + key + "\"";
                c.execute(cmd)
                db.commit()
```

Comment: I've determined that it's due to how I'm iterating over the list. I'm almost there.

Answer (score 1):

Totally messed-up! 
What's the `cats[word]` mean? 
  in cats: keys should be 'depressed', 'elated', 'hostile'
  but in word_values, they're 'angry', 'happy', 'sad', 'grateful'

I made some changes, hopefully that's what you want.

```
def accumulate_by_category(word_values, cat_sums, cats):
    for word, value in word_values.items():
        print word
        for k, v in cats.items():
            if word in v:
                print k
                if not cat_sums.has_key(k):
                    cat_sums[k] = 0
                cat_sums[k] += value
                print cat_sums
                break
```

Comment: Would this check for categories in cats, and add the values associated with the words associated with those categories into cat_sums?

Comment: I want every word that is associated with a category (via cats) to add together in cat_sum.

Comment: just copy my code into an individual file, try it and see if it's what you want.

Comment: cat_sums[k] += value
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: which was the problem I had before I modified it, and which I have with your code.

Comment: the value of cat_sums should be int, why are you using list?

Answer (score 0):

```
for cat in cats[word]
```

Does nothing, because `cats` has none of the keys `'a'`, `'angry'`, `'sad'`, etc. Since it's a defaulted dictionary, I assume you have it defaulting to an empty list, so it's the same as saying `for cat in []` each time.

If you add:

```
{'a': 4, 'angry': 0, 'sad': 0, 'grateful': 0, 'happy': 0, 'hostile': 2}
```

You will theoretically get what you want. But it's unclear from your question exactly what output you are expecting.

> Basically, what the function is trying to do, is take each of the values in `word_values`, and add those ultimately to `cat_sums`.

That's pretty unclear, since both are dictionaries. Do you mean add the values of `word_values` to the values of `cat_sums` when the keys match? When you say "add", do you mean "append"? Being precise about the result you're expecting will make things easier -- it's a lot harder to guess what you mean.